# Policy Based Routing does not work on Force10 S50N

Tags: dell, routing

As soon as I turn on PBRs on our Force10 I'll get the following message:

%ACL_AGENT-2-USRFLOW_CAM_FULL: UserFlow Cam is Full

Any idea what that means?
Basically non of the PBRs are working so I think that might be related.

Felix

Comment: Found this after some search http://ippoint.info/issue1/

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your CAM profile.

Try this:

cam-acl l2acl 4 ipv4acl 4 ipv6acl 0 ipv4qos 1 l2qos 1 l2pt 0 ipmacacl 0 vman-qos 0 ecfmacl 0 ipv4pbr 3

In any case, you should read the Force10 documentation on this issue ("CAM Tables").